# Will resetting Windows 10 overwrite Ubuntu grub?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, reset

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10. I want to reset windows but don't want to mess up with Ubuntu installation and grub which lets me choose which OS to boot up. What steps should I follow to not mess up anything and cleanly reset windows.

Comment: The Windows 10 Refresh will only modify the Windows partition.  In the worst case, you will have to run the repair Grub command, but the Refresh process shouldn't require that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will resetting Windows 10 overwrite Ubuntu GRUB?

Resetting Windows 10 will probably overwrite Ubuntu GRUB, but you can easily reinstall GRUB afterwards using the Boot Repair application. If you have the live USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu 16.10, you can boot from the Ubuntu live USB and run Boot Repair to repair the GRUB bootloader.

From the Ubuntu live USB, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

[image]

Boot Repair is available from ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for a nice find! I can't believe I couldn't find this earlier ...

Answer (score -1):

No, only reinstalling windows will overwrite grub, but if you are afraid you can reinstall grub easily from a live installation of ubuntu.